# how to dereference a linked list node data that is a pointer?

Tags: c++, dereference

so I am creating a linear linked list and I am not allowed to use static arrays or strings as data members (only dynamic char arrays)

so I have my data struct:

```
struct artists
{
    char* name;
    char* story;
    char* description;

};
```

and my node representation:

```
struct node //Create our node type for LLL of artists
{
    artists* data;
    node* next;
};
```

I am planning to allocate memory for name,description, story inside a function but my question is how do I actually dereference this?

is there such thing as `*(temp->data.name)`?

Or does this code make sense at all?

```
name = new char[strlen(artistitle)+1]
strcpy (*(temp->data.name),artistitle)
```

or would it still be `strcpy(temp->data.name,artistitle)`, since array names work similar to pointers.

I am a little confused, I might be way off, so any input will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *dereference*? Is it to free the memory that uses that node? Is it to obtain values stored in that node? If first, you can use `delete`, if second, is simmilar to what you writed: `temp->data->`[name/story/description] Where you choose what variable of `artists` do you want to use.

Comment: @Shirkam okay so then it would be strcpy(temp->data->name, artistname) , if I wanted to copy the contents of artistname into the dynamic char array that name points to?

Comment: Yup, but, you know why? If not, you should read some dynamic memory tutorials, but I will give you a pointer (bad pun). You use `->` operator when accessing values inside dynamic allocated structs and classes.

Comment: @Shirkam Thanks a lot. I am still pretty new, but I know all about *+. = ->, for some reason I couldn't come up with that. But now that you say it, I can see how dumb my question was haha. Thanks again.

Comment: First of all, you should probably be using `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: @moooeeeep The instructor who is teaching this course doesn't allow the use of string types... in absolutely none of her classes. No strings, No vectors, No global variables is literally on top of her every syllabus.

Comment: Must be that you get a feel for how it was to work with C++ back in the nineties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with dynamic memory, first thing you should have in mind is how do you allocate memory, and free it. Second, how do you access that memory.
As your question, it seems that you want to access it, besides using *dereference*.

To obtain any value from a "normal allocated" struct/class, you can use `.` so, working with, eg: the artist name, would be:

```
artists a;
//Suposse you have allocated char pointer here
strcpy(a.name, artistname);
```

If you are working with dynamic memory, you must use `->` operator as here:

```
artists *a;
//Dynamic allocate struct and char pointers
strcpy(a->name, artistname);
```

It is the same when you have nested pointers and "normal allocated":

```
node n;
//Allocate everything
strcpy(n.data->name, artistname);

//Another way to do it
node *n;
//You have to allocate node too
strcpy(n->data->name, artistname);
```

When you use a pointer as a variable, it stores the memory direction where it is *pointing* (ironic, huh). So if you do

```
node *a;
//Allocate it, and do some operations
node *b=a;
```

You are copying `a`'s **memory pointer**, not its **content**. To access a pointer's content, you can use `*` operator.